# In a Binary Search Tree what is the base of the log in this Big O notation

Tags: complexity-theory, data-structures

when discussing average time complexity as in this [table](http://bigocheatsheet.com/).

**O (log n)**

I'm assuming it is 2 but wanted to verify.  Also is it always 2 for these data structures?

I'm in the opinion that the base of the log is not considered a constant so it should be included in the Big O notation.

Whether or not is should be included.  What is the actual value?

Comment: You can read [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/78083/why-is-the-log-in-the-big-o-of-binary-search-not-base-2/78084#78084)

Comment: Very interesting math ( I see it should not be included ), but what is the actual value?

Comment: The base is not important as long as you deal with Big-O notation. For any two bases $a$ and $b$, $ \log_b{n} \in O(\log_a{n})$ and $ \log_a{n} \in O(\log_b{n})$.

Comment: I'm interested in the actual value.  The math problem has been answered already in the post by fade2black.

Comment: As David Richerby answered, its actual value depends on how you do analysis.

Comment: There is only one way to do Big O average time complexity.

Comment: @stackoverflow "There is only one way to do Big O average time complexity." Say **WHAT**??!?!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what the base of the logarithm is.  $\log_a x = (\log_bx)/\log_b a$ so changing from one (constant) base to another just introduces a constant factor. Big-$O$ and related concepts don't care about constant factors.

The base of the log is absolutely a constant: the base used for the calculations might depend on the whim (or, more likely, convenience) of the person who did the analysis but it certainly doesn't depend on the input.

Comment: "The base of the log is absolutely a constant" -- one can certainly come up with algorithms for which this is not the case, but usually it is so.